# How to display deprecated warnings when compiling from the terminal?

Tags: swift3

I am compiling swift code from the terminal using the swift compiler 3.0.1.

If I use deprecated functions such as `[NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(_:queue:completionHandler:)][sendasync]`, I do not getting any error or warning.

Is it possible to get deprecation warnings in the terminal?